# Method of Transformed Impedances

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

So I am taking an advanced optics class at the moment, using the book Lasers and Electro-Optics by Chris Davis.  At one point, while explaining the concept of impedance, he mentions something called the *method of transformed impedances*, which supposedly allows you to take a figure that looks like this:
[image]

And "transform" it so that it looks like:

[image]

The only explanation given in the text is that "It can be shown that the reflection and transmission coefficients" of these two are exactly the same, but it does not go into detail on how exactly this is achieved.  Numerically, he solves for the reflection coefficient $\rho$ using

$$
    \rho = \frac{Z_{3}^{''} - Z_{1}^{'}}{Z_{3}^{''} - Z_{1}^{'}}
$$
Where $Z_{3}^{''}$ is the "transformed impedance of medium 3 at at the boundary between 1 and 2", and is defined like
$$
    Z_{3}^{''} = Z_{2}^{'}(\frac{Z_{3}^{'}cosk_{2}d^{'} + iZ_{2}^{'}sink_{2}d^{'}}{Z_{2}^{'}cosk_{2}d^{'} + iZ_{3}^{'}sink_{2}d^{'}})
$$
where $k_{2} = \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda}$.  But there is no description of how we arrived at this conclusion, and I am confused as to what exactly it means.  How does whatever it is we did allow us to "transform" the angle of incidence to normal?  Where does the formula for $Z_{3}^{''}$ come from?

Comment: have you heard of and studied transmission lines and how they transform impedances?

Comment: No, I am taking electrodynamics concurrently with optics and we haven't reached transmission lines yet.  I also fear I don't fully understand the link between the dielectric impedance we discuss in optics and the ohmic impedance we talk about in circuit-design classes.

Comment: what you call a "dielectric impedance" is a transmission line, so you should check that out first. this is not an "ohmic impedance". as a start read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line